# Using a slider in Shiny R to filter the year

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a very basic Shiny question yet I could not find my answer in any of the others posts on this website nor others. I have a dataset about car accidents and I am trying to build an interactive map using shiny where you can choose the severity and the year and see how many accidents happened.
The severity works (using a selectinput), but the year(sliderinput) doesn't change the map outcome and I can't figure out why.

[Here's how the shiny looks like !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuXTA.png)

The slider works and the map seems to reload each time but the outcome is not correct to my data when I switch year (every year seems the same when it shouldn't).

Here's the code in fluidpage, in my sidebarpanel :

```
  #Input : slider for year
      sliderInput(inputId = "yearvar",
                  label = "Année:",
                  min = min(AccidentLondres2$Year),
                  max = max(AccidentLondres2$Year),
                  value = 1)
```

Here are a couple of methods I tried for the year but none of them worked so far, they are all in `server <- function(input, output) {` and my df is called AccidentLondres2 :

Number 1 :

```
  annee <- reactive({
    AccidentLondres2 %>% filter(Year == input$yearvar)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    var <- variableInput()
     datafiltre <- annee()
     ggplot(datafiltre) +
       geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = var)) +
       geom_sf_text(aes(label = DISTRICT), check_overlap = T, size=3) +
       scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

Number 2 :

```
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    var <- variableInput()
     datafiltre <- filter(AccidentLondres2, Year == input$yearvar)
     ggplot(datafiltre) +
       geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = var)) +
       geom_sf_text(aes(label = DISTRICT), check_overlap = T, size=3) +
       scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

Number 3 :

```
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    var <- variableInput()
     ggplot(filter(AccidentLondres2, Year == input$yearvar)) +
       geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = var)) +
       geom_sf_text(aes(label = DISTRICT), check_overlap = T, size=3) +
       scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

I am truly running out of ideas to fix it and I honestly cannot figure why it is not working. My best guest is that a filter using input$yearvar is not possible, but I don't know what to replace it with.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: in number one what if you change reactive to `eventReactive()`

Comment: Try `value = min(AccidentLondres2$Year)`.  Without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Hello, I found what my error was and it was not in the script I shared ! I had a first plot with my data grouped only by district and not by year (AccidentLondres). I then decided to do a better plot where you can change the year so I created a second dataframe (AccidentLondres2) grouped by district and year. In my script, I missed a line and forgot to change AccidentLondres to AccidentLondres2 therefore the plot not changing !

Comment: My plot is still not working though because the slider for the year will give an output of 33 values (the 33 districts) and the select will give an output of 165 values (33 districts * 5 years) and therefore the plot gives me a length error. I will write a new post on the issue if I have enough time to fix it before my project is due ! Thank you all for the help !